# Are there conventions for naming Django project, setting and main app folders?

Tags: django, naming-conventions

My Django site currently looks like this:

```
my_store/ (project folder)
    app_1/
        __init.py__
        admin.py
        apps.py
        ...
    app_2/
        __init.py__
        ...
    my_store/ (settings folder)
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ...
    store/ (main app folder)
        __init.py__
        ...
```

Where:

- `my_store` is the name of my project
- `app_1` and `app_2` are potentially reusable apps
- `store` contains project-specific logic and configuration (likely not reusable)

Are there established conventions for giving **distinct** names to each of:

- the project folder (`my_store`)
- the settings folder (`my_store`)
- the main app folder (`store`) -- I've seen a few examples of calling this "main"

*De facto / popular conventions welcome, but documented / authoritative conventions preferred.*

Answer (score 4):

I like to follow the example of doordash who kindly published a blog post on operating django at scale.

https://doordash.engineering/2017/05/15/tips-for-building-high-quality-django-apps-at-scale/

I think that it answers you specific question succinctly below, but also as some other tips.

The Django tutorial recommends a structure below:

```
mysite/ 
    mysite/
        __init__.py
polls/
    __init__.py
```

But doordash recommends a different structure:

```
mysite/
    mysite/
        __init__.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
```

I hope that this helps and has some additional details to help clarify.

Comment: is mysite/mysite an app or settings folder? is polls the main app folder?